# Script for PDF files check

Tags: linux, perl, python-3.x, pdf-generation

I wanna perform some check for PDF files. 
I wish to  check the width of pages and also figure out if the file contains double-pages.

Is there any frameworkfor that?

Thanks!

Greetings
Magda

Answer (score 2):

Indeed there is. [PDF::API2](http://p3rl.org/PDF%3a%3aAPI2) looks like it will might you what you need.

It's designed for creation and modification of PDF files.  If not, [search CPAN](http://search.cpan.org) for other PDF APIs.

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand your question, but for a start check out these utility scripts that come with the [CAM-PDF](https://metacpan.org/release/CAM-PDF) distribution. Look at the lower half of this web page, e.g. [getpdfpage.pl](http://p3rl.org/getpdfpage.pl).

A lot depends on the complexity of your PDFs, though.